# ASP.NET MVC 4 Globalization

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing, multilingual

I am new to ASP.NET and I want to design a multilingual Website.
I want to let users select their language from a menu bar on top of the home page and let them also see it on address bar of web browser.
to do so I added below codes to `RouteConfig` Class :

```
routes.MapRoute(
        name; "Default",
        url: "{lang}/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    )
```

First of all I can't Set `CultureInfo` in `CurrentThread`. I created `CultureController` and In there I set the Language based on user's choice. It won't change in other Views and Controllers. (I have heard every user get one thread when they enter website )

```
        public ActionResult ChangeLanguage ( string lang, String returnUrl = null )
        {
            if ( !new[] { "en", "fr", "ar" }.Contains( lang ) )
                throw new ArgumentException( "Language not supported." );

            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo( lang );

            if ( returnUrl == null )
                return RedirectToAction( "Index", "Home" );

            return Redirect( returnUrl );
        }
```

Second Problem: now I should pass lang in my links too and I don't want to. for example:

```
@Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home")
```

doesn't work anymore. I want the lang param get filled based on `CultureInfo` stored in `CurrentThread` or Session. ( I currently use Session ). ( Is It even possible??!! )
I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1):

1. Create an action to change the language as you did
2. Choose a language from your list or a default one (do not throw
   exception!)
3. Store it in a cookie
4. Make the redirection to the referer site (not need to pass it
   through a parameter)
5. Set the thread's languages in the Controller Initialize method
   (create a base Controller class to do this) by reading the cookie
   (if not exists or invalid set the default, send down the cookie
   again)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply!
But I have another question.you said "pass the redirection to the referer site". how should I do It? think I have link "/Home/About" which should be displayed based on chosen language of the user.The URL visitor should see is "en/Home/About" but I want to use `@Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home")` in my code and let the lang parameter get attached to URL automatically based on thread's language(and vice verse. get updated based on lang param)(the reason is when you share a french URL you don't expect other people see that link in English, and search engines.)

Comment: and another thing ( If it helps ) I have 3 column in my DB for each language. ( for example I have 3 Title Columns TitleAR, TitleEN, TitleFR ). I want to add `Title` property to my model that would return proper language based on chosen language. and now that thread's language differs all over the code I should read the language from cookies I think. do setting the thread's lang in `init` method of Controller solve this issue?

Comment: You need to create routes which are containing a parameter, call it "lang" for example (the route pattern will look something like this: "{lang}/{controller}/{action}"). You will have in the routes' data collection a lang parameter so when choosing the language, change this parameter and then make the redirect whith the HttpResponse.RedirectToRoute(string, RouteValueDictionary)). ## Yes it will solve "Title property" issue.